# Calculate percentage using active records query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following two tables

**User**

```
 UserID    UserName    UserCountry  
      1         User1       India  
      2         User2       India  
      3         User3       India  
      4         User4       China  
      5         User5       China  
      6         User6       Brazil  
      7         User7       Brazil  
      8         User8       USA  
      9         User9       USA  
     10         User10      USA
```

**Status**

```
 UserID    UserStatus  
      1         Active  
      2         Active 
      3         Inactive 
      4         Inactive
      5         Dormant
      6         Dormant
      7         Active
      8         Inactive 
      9         Active
     10         Active
```

I want to query these tables and calculate the percentage of active users arranged by country. The output in this example should be

```
 Country    Percentage  
      India      66.66%  
      China      0.00% 
      Brazil     50.00%
      USA        66.66%
```

Using the queries below, I am able to extract numerator and the denominator of the percentage formula separately but dont understand how to proceed from here. It will be best if someone can suggest how to extract the desired output in a single query.

```
@active_user = Status.where(UserStatus: “Active”).pluck(:UserID)
@active_user_bycountry = User.group(:UserCountry).where(UserID: @user_active.to_a).count(:UserID)
@total_user_bycountry = User.group(:UserCountry).count(:UserID)
```

I have searched thoroughly on SO and Google but havent found any fitting answers yet. A close answer was [Difficulty with ActiveRecord query that does percentage calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248596/difficulty-with-activerecord-query-that-does-percentage-calculation), but even this is not working for me.

Comment: Why do you have a separate table for status?

Comment: @Strawberry In the full status table we have other user statuses besides what are mentioned  above. For eg. UserID 1 is Active and also Default. However, even if it was in the same table what would be the solution to my query.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
User.joins(:status).select("users.country AS user_country", "statuses.status AS user_status", "COUNT(*) AS count", "ROUND((COUNT(*)*100.0/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statuses WHERE status = 'Active')), 2) AS percentage").where("user_status = 'Active'").group("user_country")
```

You can clone [this project](https://github.com/zulhfreelancer/rails_joins_group_count) to test it yourself.

The steps:

1. You need to `joins` the `users` and `statuses` table
2. Next, you need to `select` columns - in this case, we select 2 columns; `country` (from `users`) and `status` (from `statuses`)
3. Just for display purpose, I added another column called `count` to tell us total active users in each country
4. Next, we take total active users in each country and times by 100.0 and divide by total active users in the `statuses` table
5. Since you want 2 decimal place only, we need to use the `ROUND` function
6. We do number 4 and 5 in one long statement and we alias the result column name as `percentage`
7. We also need to tell ActiveRecord that we only want active users - look at that `where` part
8. Lastly, we need to `group` by country

Hope this helps.

**Update**

Example of the result:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+------------+
| id | user_country | user_status | count | percentage |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+------------+
|    | Brazil       | Active      | 7     | 20.59      |
|    | China        | Active      | 9     | 26.47      |
|    | India        | Active      | 11    | 32.35      |
|    | USA          | Active      | 7     | 20.59      |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: In your query the percentage is calculated as (total active users in a country)*100/(total active users across countries) whereas i intended to ask (total active users in a country)*100/(total users of any status in that country). I tried improvising your query at my end but couldnt get the answer. Please see if you can take a stab at it again.